# what kind of sort is this? - Java

Tags: java, sorting

Does anyone know what kind of sort this is in java?  I'm not quite sure myself. Insertion? selection?  Thanks in advance!

```
    public class sorting {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      String[] arr = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Fruit", "Watermelon", "Hello World"};
        String tmp;
        for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
        {
          tmp = arr[i];
          for (int j = 0;j < arr.length;j++)
          {
            if (i == j) continue;
            int x = tmp.compareTo(arr[j]);
            if (x < 0)
            {
              tmp = arr[j];
              arr[j] = arr[i];
              arr[i] = tmp;
            }
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
          System.out.println(arr[i]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think it is Bubble sort see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort. But it is some kind of not optimized version :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) implementation:

- It's `O(n^2)`
- At each step the greatest element "bubbles up" to the correct position
- A swap is being performed for "bubbling up" the elements

Although Bubble sort *is* ugly to begin with, we can do a little less work by correctly setting up the indexes, and eliminate that `i == j` comparison in the process:

```
for (int i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
        int x = arr[j].compareTo(arr[j + 1]);
        if (x > 0) {
            tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = tmp;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort. A lexicographical bubble sort, to be specific.

Comment: You probably meant lexicographical.  The word lexicological has a meaning unrelated to sort order.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
{//outer loop
    tmp = arr[i];
    for (int j = 0;j < arr.length;j++)
    {//inner loop
        if (i == j) continue;
        int x = tmp.compareTo(arr[j]);
        if (x < 0)
        {
            tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

As you could tell that in the inner loop, it compare with node near by and move just one step.
Each time it will start from outer loop's index and retrieve through the rest of data again.
Seems it is a bubble sort, but it is a weird implement.